# Were it not for VS Had it not been for

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

The following is part of writing on the Navajo Code Talkers during the second world war.

*One Marine Corps signal officer summed up the situation after the war: "Were it not for the Navajo Code Talkers, the Marines would never have taken Iwo Jima and other places". *

Why does the writer use "were it not for" instead of "had it not been for"?
Is it possible grammatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both mean exactly the same in this context. The use is simply the writer's preference.
 *"were it not for"* is, perhaps, is slightly less common but can be used when discussing both the past and the present.
 *"Were it not for lack of time, I could have gone to the shops"*
 *"Were it not for lack of time, I could be going to the shops"*
Whilst *"had it not been for"* can only be used for past events.

Comment: ...What about this sentence..For example, if it was not for the aid received by the European countries after the World War 2 from the US under marshal plan,they tremendously would have to struggle to reach where they are today. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Th sentence is slightly wrong, it should be _"If **were** not for the aid received by the European countries after the World War 2 from the US under marshal plan,they would have to struggle **tremendously** to reach where they are today. "_. In general the adverb should be as close to the verb as possible. and the Marshal Plan was a past event _**was**_ could be interpreted as ongoing.

Comment: ..is it 'if were' or 'if it were'? Can we also use would have had  instead of would have?

Comment: Sorry, my typo, Yes it should be _"If it were not..."_ or alternatively _"Were it not ... "_.  Yes _"would have had"_ instead of _"would have"_ are equally valid in this context.

Comment: ..Thanks Sir. One last question is in a conditional sentence can we always use would have and would have had interchangeably in the main clause.

Comment: In this case they are interchangeable, but probably not always. 
I think it best if you asked this as a new question and get some other opinions, I'm not sure. Please include 1 or 2 examples for clarification.